# How can I pass a class member's fixed size array by reference?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I have a class Node that contains a fixed-size array. I have another class that creates an instance myNode and calls a function to assign 5 values to the fields in the array. I want to pass the array by reference so the function modifies the actual array and not a copy, but I can't figure out how.

Node:

```
class Node
{
public:
    // Constructor, destructor, other members, etc
    uint8_t mArray[5];
}
```

Worker:

```
class worker
{
    void doStuff(uint8_t (&arr)[5])
    {
        arr[0] = 12;
        arr[1] = 34;
        arr[2] = 56;
        arr[3] = 78;
        arr[4] = 90;
    }

    int main()
    {
        Node *myNode = new Node();
        doStuff(myNode->mArray);
        // myNode->mArray is not modified
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your actual code, a [mcve]. The code you posted isnt that, for example `main` isnt a member function (you can have a member called `main` but then where is your actual `main`?), missing `;` and maybe more. Then explain how the code fails to do what it is supposed to do, add compiler error messages when there are any

Comment: works as expected after fixing the obvious errors (that are not related to passing the array) https://godbolt.org/z/MGx6MGcvK

Comment: `std::array` has much nicer semantics than C-style arrays.  You can pass it by value or by reference, just like any other object.

Comment: @pnapster "*myNode->mArray is not modified*" - [can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/ev7tQu)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Wow I am stupid... I was simply printing the array wrong instead of using a for loop. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I dont know if you are stupid, but I think you didnt take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that is just a couple of clicks away from this link [mcve]. If you had created a mcve chances are high that you already find the mistake before posting the quesiton, if not we can help you to fix it. The code you did post does not contain the bug in your real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the array is modified. A minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

class Node {
public:
    uint8_t mArray[5];
};

class worker {
    void doStuff(uint8_t (&arr)[5]) {
        arr[0] = 12;
        arr[1] = 34;
        arr[2] = 56;
        arr[3] = 78;
        arr[4] = 90;
    }

public:
    int main() {
        Node *myNode = new Node();
        doStuff(myNode->mArray);
        for(auto v : myNode->mArray) {
            std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>(v) << ' ';
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
        delete myNode;
        return 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    worker w;
    return w.main();
}
```

This prints the expected:

```
12 34 56 78 90
```

It'd be easier if you took a `Node&` in the function though:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

class Node {
public:
    uint8_t mArray[5];
};

class worker {
    void doStuff(Node& n) {
        n.mArray[0] = 12;
        n.mArray[1] = 34;
        n.mArray[2] = 56;
        n.mArray[3] = 78;
        n.mArray[4] = 90;
        // or just:
        // n = Node{12,34,56,78,90};
    }

public:
    int main() {
        Node *myNode = new Node();
        doStuff(*myNode);
        // ...
        delete myNode;
        return 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    worker w;
    return w.main();
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I was just about to post a [similar example](https://ideone.com/ev7tQu) showing the array being modified.

Comment: Wow I am stupid... I was simply printing the array wrong instead of using a for loop. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A C-style array is never copied when passed by value in a parameter. When passed as an ordinary argument, it decays into a pointer to the first element. So, you don't need to use a reference, just use an ordinary pointer or array parameter.

```
class worker
{
    void doStuff(uint8_t arr[5]) // same as uint8_t *arr
    {
        arr[0] = 12;
        arr[1] = 34;
        arr[2] = 56;
        arr[3] = 78;
        arr[4] = 90;
    }

    int main()
    {
        Node *myNode = new Node();
        doStuff(myNode->mArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: "*A C-style array is never copied when passed as a parameter. It's converted to a pointer to the first element*" - that true only if the array is passed by value, as it is in your example. The array will decay into a pointer. But that is not true when the array is passed by reference, as the OP wants.

Comment: I've clarified the answer.